# failed to get latitude , longitude using google maps , get_lat_long_from_address

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi i am trying to get `latitude` and `longitude` values by `address`

```
function get_lat_long_from_address($address)
{

    $lat = 0;
    $lng = 0;

    if ($this->geocodeCaching) { // if caching of geocode requests is activated

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->database(); 
        $CI->db->select("latitude,longitude");
        $CI->db->from("geocoding");
        $CI->db->where("address", trim(strtolower($address)));
        $query = $CI->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return array($row->latitude, $row->longitude);
        }

    }

    $data_location = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ", "+", $address)."&sensor=".$this->sensor;
    if ($this->region!="" && strlen($this->region)==2) { $data_location .= "&region=".$this->region; }
    $data = file_get_contents($data_location);

    $data = json_decode($data);

    if ($data->status=="OK") {

        $lat = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        if ($this->geocodeCaching) { // if we to need to cache this result
            $data = array(
                "address"=>trim(strtolower($address)),
                "latitude"=>$lat,
                "longitude"=>$lng
            );
            $CI->db->insert("geocoding", $data);
        }

    }

    return array($lat, $lng);

}
```

the thing is whatever th address i pass to the function it returns only `(0,0)`  for latitude and longitude .

i passed the address like

```
$address = "colombo,sri lanka"; 
$address = "colombo,LK";
$address = "newyork,United states";
$address = "1/35 amunugama gunnena,kandy,sri lanka";
```

but every time it returns `(0,0)`  ,

why is this , what is the address format i need to use , please help . thanks in advance .........

Comment: Do you have `(0,0)` in your cache? The call to the maps API is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what value and URL you are getting exactly, so I tried in the browser with your input URL

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=colombo,sri+lanka&sensor=true

which gives the correct result.

Make sure your URL is creating correctly.

To see the output for debug, you can print like
   print_r ($data);

Also the suggestion is put the CodeIgniter in your tag list.

Comment: actually when print_r it displays 0,0

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya: `sensor` can be `true` or `false`: both are valid. You should be doing something when `$data->status` is NOT `"OK"` to check what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your address format should be like this" 13 Telfer Court Rowville VIC 3178 Australia" 
Try this one it worked for me